# Prompt user until 5 unique vowels or consonants have been input

Tags: python

The purpose of the code is best explained below, for example if I were to enter 'hello' then 'luck' then 'liar' the proper outputs should be '5' 'eouia' 3' and 'ckr'. When I do this however it keeps prompting me for more inputs after entering 'liar'.

```
        ###########################################################
        #  Algorithm
        #    Ask for a word
        #     Count and store all vowels in the words (repeats only are 
        #      counted once)
        #     count and store only consonants after the last vowel, if the 
        #     if last letter is a vowel no consonants are stored
        #       once all 5 vowels are stored or at least 5 consonants are 
        #       stored 
        #           print
        #               what vowels appear and how many 
        #               what consonants appear   
        ###########################################################

VOWELS = 'aeiou'

word = input('Input a word: ')
wordlow = word.lower() #converts the input to all lowercase

vowcount = 0
concount = 0

vowcollected_str = ''
concollected_str = ''

#ends the program once 5 vowels or consonants have been stored
while vowcount <= 4 and concount <= 4: 
    vowcount = 0
    concount = 0

    #stores the actual letter that is being stored, not just how many
    vowcollected_str = ''
    concollected_str = ''

    for i, ch in enumerate(wordlow):
        if ch in VOWELS:
            if ch not in vowcollected_str:
                vowcollected_str += ch 
                position = i
                vowcount += len(vowcollected_str)
        if ch not in VOWELS:
                if ch not in concollected_str:
                    concollected_str += wordlow[i:]
                    concount += len(word[i:]) 
    word = input('Input a word: ')
    wordlow = word.lower()
print(vowcount)
print(vowcollected_str) 
print(concount)
print(concollected_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) of the all the required vowels and subtract all the letters you input until the set is empty:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

vowelsSoFar = set(VOWELS)

while vowelsSoFar:
    word = input('enter a word: ')
    vowelsSoFar -= set(word)
    # Feel free to print out the remains vowels, for example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions to get the vowels and return the `len`.

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


words =  'hello', 'luck', 'liar'

seen_vowels = "".join(c for w in words for c in w if c in "aeiou")
seen_vowels
# 'eouia'

len(seen_vowels)
# 5
```

Trailing consonants could be found via `takewhile` of each reversed word.

```
trailing_cons = "".join("".join(it.takewhile(lambda x: x not in "aeiou", w[::-1]))[::-1] for w in words)
trailing_cons
# 'ckr'
```

---

**Details**

Note, `takewhile` grabs all consonants before the first observed vowel.  By reversing each word, we get the trailing consonants.

```
"".join(it.takewhile(lambda x: x not in "aeiou", "luck"[::-1]))
# 'kc'
```